# Circle Bundles of surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let S be a surface with a metric of constant curvature and finite area. Is there a classification of the circle bundles over S?

Comment: What do you mean by "classification"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "circle bundle"? The true bundles are classified by $H^2$, with metric and area completely irrelevant.

Comment: I mean a bundle whose the fibers are circles. By classification i mean one way of distinguish the total spaces.

Answer (score 3):

See [this wikipedia article on Seifert Fibered Spaces.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_fiber_space)

Answer (score 0):

Flat orientable circle bundles (topological, not necessarily linear) are classified by homeomorphisms of the fundamental group to $homeo^+(S^1)$, and these are in a weak sense (up to topological semiconjugacy) classified by their bounded Euler class as an element in $H^2_b(S,Z)$, the second bounded cohomology with integer coefficients. This group fits into a sequence $Hom(\pi_1S,R/Z)\to H^2_b(S,Z)\to H_2^b(S,R)$ and $H_b^2(S,R)$ is infinite-dimensional by Brooks-Series.

See Ghys' Survey Paper "Groups acting on the circle".